# Change the background color from db in css

Tags: php, sql, css

i have table in db sql

```
CREATE TABLE `Tools` (
    `Id_Tools` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `N_Imagelogo` varchar(100),
    `Back_Co` varchar(15),
    PRIMARY KEY (`Id_Tools`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and i have file css it's style.php

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/css");
 require_once('config.php');

mysql_select_db($database_config, $config);
$query_Tools = sprintf("SELECT * FROM Tools");
$Tools = mysql_query($query_Tools, $config) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Tools = mysql_fetch_assoc($Tools); 
?>
body {
background-color:<?php echo $row_Tools['Back_Co'];?>;
}
```

Connect to the database is correctly output also graduated right
but file css (background-color) not work

Comment: What does `config.php` do?

Comment: Please define "not work"

Comment: What does the output look like?  Do you get an error (make sure it isn't suppressed)?

Comment: What does the generated HTML look like?

Comment: Shouldn't the max character length be 6 or 7 characters. `#00ff00` basicly with or with out the `#`.  Just curious if your even getting what you want from that table column.

Comment: If you access `style.php` directly can you confirm the CSS has correctly been outputted to the file. If it has then this is not a PHP or MySQL issue, but rather a CSS issue where you are not correctly setting the background-color.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You would want to use a CSS preprocessor like http://pcss.wiq.com.br/ to have the css sheet generated on the server side, pulling from your database. You will not be able to use php variables or anything pulled from a Mysql table directly in a regular CSS sheet

Comment: It's not a regular CSS style sheet hence the filename `style.php`. OP is making their own CSS pre-processor.